# getting the old scroll offset using the Package flutter_webview_plugin

Tags: flutter

i am trying to integrate a Webview in a Test app using the Package [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-readme-tab-)

my goal is to hide a bottomNavigationBar when the User scroll up in the Webview and show it, when the user scroll down.

in the mentioned Package there is a [listner](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#listen-for-scroll-event-in-webview) to listen to vertical Schroll changes :

```
final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
flutterWebviewPlugin.onScrollYChanged.listen((double offsetY) { // latest offset value in vertical scroll
  // compare vertical scroll changes here with old value
});
```

the offsetY value, is the current value, but how can't i get the old value, to compare it with the new value ?  any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i have implemented a solution to this.

i have defined a variable `oldOffset = 0.0` and in the method `trackOffsetChange` i checked if `oldOffset` value smaller than the `currentOffset` value. if it's the case then `oldOffset` get the value of `currentOffset` and with `setState` i rebuild the widget to hide the `BottomNavBar`, else show the `BottomNavBar`.

here is the whole code of the test App, if someone new like me, is interested to see the source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: WebInApp(),
    );
  }
}

class WebInApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebInAppState createState() => _WebInAppState();
}

class _WebInAppState extends State<WebInApp> {
  bool _isVisible = true;
  double oldOffset = 0.0;
  final flutterWebOlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  void trackOffsetChange(double currentOffset) {
    print('current Offset --->> $currentOffset');
    print('old Offset --->> $oldOffset');

    if (oldOffset < currentOffset) {
      print('old Offset In -- IF --->> $oldOffset');
      oldOffset = currentOffset;
      setState(() {
        _isVisible = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isVisible = true;
      });

      print('old Offset In -- ESLE --->> $oldOffset');
      oldOffset = currentOffset;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterWebOlugin.onScrollYChanged.listen((double yOffset) {
      trackOffsetChange(yOffset);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      url: "https://play.google.com/store/apps",
//      hidden: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebView'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
        height: _isVisible ? 60.0 : 0.0,
        child: bottomNav(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class bottomNav extends StatelessWidget {
  const bottomNav({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.forward),
          title: Text('back'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          title: Text('forward'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```